# Show That T is diagonalizable if A is.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in M_2(F)$ and let $ T: M_2(F) \rightarrow M_2(F)$ be the linear transformation $T(X) = AX$

Let $\underline{0}\ne \underline{v} = (a_1, a_2) \in F^2$ be an eigen tuple of $A$. (Find an eigen vector $\underline{u} \ne \underline{0}$ of $T$.)

Show that if $A$ is diagonalizable then so is $T$.

$T$ is diagonalizable if there $\exists$ a basis of eigen vectors. However there can only be two eigen tuples as the basis of $F^2$, how can I then find 4 distinct eigen vectors for the basis of $ M_2(F)$?

Comment: Try $u_i u_j^T$. These form a basis.

Comment: I have $u = (\underline{v}, \underline{v})$, this forms a basis? The basis does not need to be length 4?

Comment: Suppose $u_1,u_2$ form a basis of eigenvectors of $A$. Then the matrices $u_i u_j^T$, $i,j = 1,2$ form a basis of $M_2(F)$. Apply $T$ to these matrices.

Comment: The transposition is on the second column , or the entire matrix ?